# c++ vector of structs inside class

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, struct

hello all i am working on a school prject called inventory inquisitor. the specifications are as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X85so.png)

so far i have created a class in which contains a struct and a vector of this struct.
all im trying to do so far is get the class to display the struct just to know it works but when i compile it and run it nothing happens. here is the code. excuse whatever rookie mistakes i have made i am very new with classes, and vectors. thanks you in advance!

```
//Inventory Inquisitor.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype> //for toupper
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Inventory
{
  private:
  struct item
   {
  string Description = " ";
  double Quantity = 0;
  double Wholesalescost = 0;
  double Retailcost = 0;
  string Dateadded = " ";
   };
   vector<item> Inv;
public:
  void Display();

};

void Inventory::Display()
{ 

 Inv[0].Description = "english";
 Inv[0].Quantity = 1;
 Inv[0].Wholesalescost = 100;
 Inv[0].Retailcost = 200;
 Inv[0].Dateadded = "3/8/2018";
 cout << Inv[0].Description << endl;
 cout << Inv[0].Quantity << endl;
 cout << Inv[0].Wholesalescost << endl;
 cout << Inv[0].Retailcost << endl;
 cout << Inv[0].Dateadded << endl;
}

int main()
{
 Inventory inst1;

  inst1.Display();

 }
```

Comment: In `Display`, `Inv.size() == 0`. You need to put an `item` into the vector.

Comment: When first learning to use vectors repalce `vector_name[some_number]` with `vector_name.at(some_number)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i dont seem to be understanding what you are reffering to i replaced vector_name[some_number] with vector_name.at(some_number) and now i am getting an error terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put something into the vector before accessing it:

```
// Create an item
item i;
i.Description = "english";
i.Quantity = 1;
i.Wholesalescost = 100;
i.Retailcost = 200;
i.Dateadded = 3/8/2018;

// The vector is empty, size() == 0    
// Add it to the vector
Inv.push_back(i);
// Now the vector has 1 item, size() == 1

// Now you can print it
cout << Inv.at(0).Description << endl;
cout << Inv.at(0).Quantity << endl;
cout << Inv.at(0).Wholesalescost << endl;
cout << Inv.at(0).Retailcost << endl;
cout << Inv.at(0).Dateadded << endl;
```

According to your assignment, you will most likely change to function to print an existing item. You will have another function to add items to the vector.

```
void Inventory::Display(int index)
{ 
    // Print an item already in the vector
    if (index >= 0 && index < Inv.size()) {
        cout << Inv.at(index).Description << endl;
        cout << Inv.at(index).Quantity << endl;
        cout << Inv.at(index).Wholesalescost << endl;
        cout << Inv.at(index).Retailcost << endl;
        cout << Inv.at(index).Dateadded << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: awsome thank you for the detailed explanation i had thought i created the item on line 22 "vector<item> Inv" with Inv. but now i understand. thanks Johnny i appreciate it!